# Deleting a particular row using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am working a web app where I am creating a invoice for the items purchased. Now in the invoice I am having to extra lines for additional charges like transportation and other services, but I can leave them blank and so they do not produce any tax. I have also provided the DELETE provision for the same. But when I am click on DELETE it is deleting the rows, but the tax % summary has the record of 0% tax unnecessarily. I am using JQUERY for the same. Here is the code :

This is how I am calling it and below it is the function:

```
<label  class="btn btn-default" name="delrow<?php echo $cnt;?>" id="delrow<?php echo $cnt;?>" onclick="delverycdel(<?php echo $cnt; ?>);

function delverycdel(a)
{       
     var count = $("#count").val();
     var hsncode22 = $("input[name='hsnper[]']").length;
     console.log("hsncode : "+hsncode22);
     if(count>1)
     {
         $("taxc"+a).remove();
         var elem = document.getElementById("taxc"+a); 
         elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
         var tc = parseInt(count)-1;
         $("#count").val(tc);
         SetDefault(a, "xyz");
         return false;
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't you remove taxc when the count is == 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You are removing element then again get element by id. Which will be undefined so search for child first than remove both

```
if(count>1)
     {

         var elem = document.getElementById("taxc"+a); 
         $("taxc"+a).remove(); // add remove here
         elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
         var tc = parseInt(count)-1;
         $("#count").val(tc);
         SetDefault(a, "xyz");
         return false;
    }
```